# Will AngularJs ng class to dynamically change the css

Tags: angularjs

How to apply the css class dynamically in ng-class based on condition.

**Code:**
    `<input type="text" id="ProcessRight_SearchUserLeft" class="inputSearch" placeholder="Search" ng-model="selectedUserOne" ng-class=""/>`

Question:
if i have condition bool selecteduser if it is true red want to apply otherwise green want to apply

Comment: you want to apply css dynamically? is it?

Comment: You need to be more specific with what you want help with. Please explain further.

Comment: yes now i have edited.

Comment: What condition ? Which class ?

Comment: if i have condition bool selecteduser if it is true red want to apply otherwise  green want to apply.

Comment: So both red and green apply ?

Answer (score 1):

If you are asking if you can change the css class dynamically with ng-class. The answer is yes.

For example, if in your view you could set a field in your model to true and then dynamically set the class attribute using ng-class based on the value of that field.

```
<!-- toggle a variable to true or false -->
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="someclass"> Use Some Class?
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="someotherclass"> Use Some Other Class?

<!-- add the class 'some-class' if the variable 'someclass' is true -->
<div ng-class="{ 'some-class': someclass, 'some-other-class': someotherclass }">
```

Comment: @SanthoseKumar glad to be of help.